# How can I include a collection's foreign key property in the controller query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This may be a case of "going too deep", but I thought I would ask anyway.  I've got the following models:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    //...other Exam properties
    public virtual ICollection<ExamResults> Results {get; set;}
}

public class ExamResults
{
    public int ExamId {get; set;}
    //...other Exam Result properties
    public int ExamDomainId {get; set;}
    public virtual ExamDomain ExamDomain {get; set;}
}

public class ExamDomain
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public String DomainName {get; set;}
    //...more stuff
}
```

So in plain English, an Exam has a collection of ExamResults.  Each ExamResult has an ExamDomain, and each ExamDomain has a name.

The problem is this: My view creates a new database query every time I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(e => e.exampleResult.ExamDomain.DomainName)
```

I cannot include ExamDomain in the initial controller query, as Exam does not have a navigation property with Exam.  Example:

```
//The below does not work because ExamResults is a collection, not a record
var exam = db.Exams.Include(e => e.ExamResults.ExamDomain)...

//The code below also does not work, but it does run
var exam = db.Exams.Include(e =
```

With that said, how can I grab all the necessary DomainNames from the ExamDomain table without running an additional query for every ExamResult?

PS: I do have a view model, but it shouldn't matter for the purpose of this question.

Comment: `public virtual ExamDomain {get; set;}` This is not compilable. Do you mean `public virtual ExamDomain Domain {get; set;}` ?

Comment: Also, yes a view model matters for this question. You are not using ViewModels properly if using an object in your view causes another query. A IQueryable object should never reach you view or view model.

Comment: You will have to forgive my novice approach.  I'm fairly new to MVC, and I'm still in the process of learning.  Rather than show you my novice view model, what kind of view model would you create?

Comment: Either put POCOs without any percistance into view models, or build a view model based on the entity

Comment: Well, lets assume the viewmodel would look identical to the Exam model, for now.

Comment: But it doesn't. Or you wouldnt have that problem. Either this statement is false `My view creates a new database query every time I use[...]` or the problem is in code you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here for including properites hidden below collections.

Firstly the string .Include syntax should just work:

```
   db.Exams.Include("ExamResults.ExamDomain")
```

or my personal preference using a lambda:

```
   db.Exams.Include(e => e.ExamResults.Select(r=>r.ExamDomain))
```

Checkout RoMillers (from EF) post on how to use lambda includes. He also talks about collection based include in this post http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/